# gedit can notdisplay for no reason

Tags: gedit

[Always been like that, even sudo added.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LiUsx.png)

My tutor force me to use gedit, can anyone help me?

Besides, the display is empty, I don't know why, maybe is path wrong.

I don't know how to set a path for gedit.

Comment: what are you running this on? do you have a GUI running at all?

Comment: This looks a lot like you're using WSL, because `DESKTOP-RANDOMCODE` is a Windows automated hostname generation mechanism.  Are you using WSL?

Comment: Ive had problems running gedit with sudo. The latest way I use is to use the '-E' option. So i just run "sudo -E gedit /path/to/file". It works ok. It sends alot of text to stderr on the term though.